# Is it okay to get new Firebase ID token on page load?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Is it okay to run `user.getIdToken(true)` whenever the page is first loaded or whenever users hit the browser refresh button? Any performance, security or other issues I should be aware of?

---

#### More detail

I am relying on custom claims to handle user roles. As Doug suggested in [his Medium post](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/patterns-for-security-with-firebase-supercharged-custom-claims-with-firestore-and-cloud-functions-bb8f46b24e11) I've made sure to get a new ID token with `user.getIdToken(true)`:

```
let lastCommitted
function onNewClaims(snapshot) {
    const data = snapshot.data()
    console.log('New claims doc\n', data)
    if (data._lastCommitted) {
        if (lastCommitted &&
              !data._lastCommitted.isEqual(lastCommitted)) {
            // Force a refresh of the user's ID token
            console.log('Refreshing token')
            currentUser.getIdToken(true)
        }
        lastCommitted = data._lastCommitted
    }
}
```

But as far as I understand this snippet only gets triggered when users are *currently* in the app. If claims are updated while users are away (e.g. closed tabs) they won't receive new updates. I looked through docs and couldn't find any best practices regarding `getIdToken`.

Since ID token lasts an hour and gets updated when users sign out and back in, I feel like I am doing something wrong with force refreshing ID token too often. (Users could potentially hit refresh 5-100 times or more and ID token gets refreshed every single time)

---

#### Edit

Here's an example use case: a project management app (e.g. Trello) where users can belong to different team workspaces. Admin users can invite users or assign them different roles. Roles are then stored as individual user's custom claims (e.g. [teamId]: "member").

If users are currently in the app `user.getIdToken` gets called when claims are updated. (e.g. admin changes the users' role from "member" to "admin") But if the users are not in the app, nothing gets called. When they come back, their claims *in Firestore doc* are up to date ("admin") when their *actual* claims are not, ("member") because force refresh logic doesn't get triggered when the page is loaded.

As far as I understand `auth.onIdTokenChanged` never gets called because `user.getIdToken` (force refresh on the client) doesn't get called in the first place. So I was thinking this might make more sense:

```
const updated = lastCommitted && !data._lastCommitted.isEqual(lastCommitted)
let loaded = false // set to true when app starts/restarts (page refresh)

// Instead of this
if (updated) {
 //...
}

// Do this?
if (!loaded || updated) {
 //...
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by refreshing the ID token on every page reload?

Comment: Also in that post I mention that there is a listener `auth.onIdTokenChanged` for ID tokens that you should use when you want to know immediately when the token is new or changed.  Why are you not using that instead?  In the article I only force refresh the token when I know it's been changed because the backing document also changed.  The force is necessary in that case because I don't want to wait for the old token to expire.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for your comment. I've added example use case.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks! I did read that listener part but `auth.onIdTokenChanged` and `await currentUser.getIdTokenResult(false)` will still return old token (at least from my experience) since `user.getIdToken` only runs when `_lastCommitted` are outdated but it's always up to date when page is refreshed.